# How to sort object array based on key in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I have a candidate object with properties

```
candidateid:number;
name:string;
```

I wish to sort an array of such objects based on the `name` property. How can I achieve this in TypeScript in angular 2?

Answer (score 164):

It's the same as plain old javascript. You can still use an arrow function to make it more concise.

```
x.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0)
```

Or using **localeCompare**.

```
x.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Comment: Or use `localeCompare`.

Comment: `localeCompare` - must have been a brit that wrote it... does not work in node fwi

Comment: Nested ternaries may be more concise, but they are harder to read.

Comment: I get in node js `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)`

Comment: @Jonathan do you know why it does not work in `nodejs`? node and browser js use the same js engine..