# Apply array.sort() default algorithm to string properties of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

From `Array.prototype.sort()` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The default sort order is built upon converting the elements into
>   strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

What if target array's elements are objects and we want apply above algorithm to `targetKey`'s value?

```
const targetArray = [
    { targetKey: 'March' },
    { targetKey: 'Jan' },
    { targetKey: 'Feb' },
    { targetKey: 'Dec' }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    { targetKey: 'Dec' },
    { targetKey: 'Feb' },
    { targetKey: 'Jan' },
    { targetKey: 'March' }
]
```

Some simple solutions?

**Warning**: We don't considering the ordering by alphabet in this question. We need to order due sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

Comment: Have you tried something or just looking for someone to write it for you?

Comment: @KoshVery, No. Currently, I need to know, are some simple solutions exists or no. If no - I'll find the complicated solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value) and [How to sort object array based on key in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850339) and [Sort Array of Objects by specific key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816557) and [Sort Array of object by object field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194830)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `compareFunction` function with [String::localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) on the target keys:

```js
const targetArray = [
    { targetKey: 'March' },
    { targetKey: 'Jan' },
    { targetKey: 'Feb' },
    { targetKey: 'Dec' }
];

targetArray.sort((a, b) => a.targetKey.localeCompare(b.targetKey));

console.log(targetArray)
```

And if you don't want to mutate (modify) the original array, you can clone it with `slice()` and then sort the cloned one.

```js
const targetArray = [
    { targetKey: 'March' },
    { targetKey: 'Jan' },
    { targetKey: 'Feb' },
    { targetKey: 'Dec' }
];

let res = targetArray.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a.targetKey.localeCompare(b.targetKey));

console.log(targetArray)
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [destructing assingment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `targetKey` and then use [`.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare both values:

```js
const targetArray = [
    { targetKey: 'March' },
    { targetKey: 'Jan' },
    { targetKey: 'Feb' },
    { targetKey: 'Dec' }
],

res = targetArray.sort(({targetKey:a}, {targetKey:b}) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Intl.collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator)

```js
const targetArray = [
    { targetKey: 'March' },
    { targetKey: 'Jan' },
    { targetKey: 'Feb' },
    { targetKey: 'Dec' }
];

let op = targetArray.sort(({targetKey:a},{targetKey:b})=>new Intl.Collator('en').compare(a,b));

console.log(op)
```